# AIX Clear contents of files larger than 100 MB

Tags: shell, aix

I am looking for a command for clearing all files in a directory that has become more than 100 MB. I am using an AIX box and it is generating logs that are filling the space quickly. I do not wish to delete the files. Just want to clear the contents.

Comment: What is 100 MB? The files? Or is the size of the directory itself 100 MB?

What do you mean with "clear the contents"? If you truncate the files to 0 bytes, would that be acceptable? Why not delete them instead? Or compress them?

Comment: Compressing is a good option. I shall explore that. I cannot delete as once deleted the system cannot create the file.

Comment: Depending upon which application is creating the log files, there may be an application specific solution such as rotatelogs or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the progs don't keep a file handle open, you can use

```
find yourLogDir -type f -size +100M -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

Edit, see comments:
When the M flag is not supported on your system, enter a long number.

Comment: I tested this a little bit on AIX 6.1.  The 100M syntax I believe is not really working.  Its probably safer to put +104857600 (or whatever size you want).  It seems to be more reliable / portable.

Comment: @pedz Tx. I do not have a AIX at home, so I could not verify my solution. I thought Sandeep would understand when the M syntax wasn't supported. And he did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
find LogDir -type f -size +104857600c -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

The 'c' after 104857600 indicates that the number is in bytes

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging on @WalterA's answer on my AIX machine. It looks like we have to change the provided command a bit:

```
find yourLogDir -type f -size +(multiple of 512 Bytes) -exec cp {} /dev/null \;
```

For example, if you want to copy a log file with a size of more than 100 MB, just execute the below command with proper directory path:

```
find yourLogDir -type f -size +204800 -exec cp {} <dir path to copy> \;
```